# How to return back to browser after it sends Intent to start my app without exiting from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have such tricky thing declared in Manifest to be able to start my app from a browser:

```
<activity android:name=".BrowserIntentCallBackActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:scheme="trickyapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

this workds ok and starts my `BrowserIntentCallBackActivity` as expected. If my app wasnt previously started then finishing the `BrowserIntentCallBackActivity` returns user back to browser and its fine.
 
However if my app was previuosly started and is running on background finishing the `BrowserIntentCallBackActivity` returns user to previuos activity of my app. But I want to send user back to browser where he/she clicked the very special link and from where my `BrowserIntentCallBackActivity` was launched by `intent`. And I dont want ot kill my running app.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the launch mode of your activity:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

I believe the correct mode for your task will be "singleTask" or maybe "singleInstance", although I have limited experience with those so you will have to experiment to be sure.

Comment: Note, if you sometimes launch the activity from within as well, you can try setting the launch mode on the intent, rather than in the manifest, so it will behave differently depending on if it comes from the browser or internally.

Comment: I was thinking that way (I mean setting the launch mode flags of activity) but thought that smb could tell exactly which params/flags to use. Also there is a plenty of hidden behaviors like if you use singleInstance then clicking Home (sending app to bg) gonna kill activity as well which is not an option.

Comment: Yes, those two flags are pretty uncommonly used, for a reason.